# Wireguard not routing incoming traffic

Tags: networking, wireguard

I have Wireguard setup as a VPN on my Server with my Phone as a peer. Routing on the Server it self works without a problem, but it seems like all the traffic coming from my Phone is just ignored. When I ping `1.1.1.1` for example (from my phone), I can see the Packets in `tcpdump` on the server but they seem to not get routet (at least they don't show up at the destination and I don't get a response)

the weird thing is that I have another server setup with basicly the same config (different keys, different Subnet) and that one seems to work

**What I've checked**

- Peer is connected
- Data sent by Peer ist recieved by Server and vice versa
- Client can Ping server via the Tunnel
- `ip route show table 1201` shows equivalent results on both servers
- `ip route list` shows similar results
- `ip route get 1.1.1.1` shows that the Traffic should be routet via the default gateway on the Server
- Server has `net.ipv4.ip_forward` set to `1`

Server config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.1.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
Table = 1201
PrivateKey = <key>

# Phone
[Peer]
PublicKey = <key>
PresharedKey = <key>
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.3/32
```

TLDR: Wireguard running on Server (A) does not route traffic coming from peer (B)

- Pinging Server A from Peer B works
- Pinging Peer B from Server A works
- Pinging any Server C from Server A works
- Pinging any Server C from Peer B doesn't work

Comment: You have to either do NAT or tell your next hop how to reach the 10.1.1.0/24 subnet. However, home and enduser questions are offtopic.